# Setting "useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest" to true in settings.JSON doesn't complete brackets after function autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've also tried writing `"go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true` but neither one of them seems to work (I've tried on C and JS files).

My settings.JSON:

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.fontSize": 22,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
    "useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true,

    "[json]": {
    
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
    },
}
```

My only installed extensions are `C/C++` and `Code Runner`.

How can I achieve autocomplete of functions with parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Complete Function Calls` in vs settings and enable it.